# How to write a custom pooling layer in Theano?

Tags: python, theano, deep-learning

I am new to Theano, and I try to learn Theano's source code. However, the Theano implementation on [MaxPooling](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/tensor/signal/downsample.py) completely confused me. Especially, in its pooling's grad definition, it goes for another MaxPoolGrad, and this MaxPoolGrad's grad method further goes for DownsampleFactorMaxGradGrad.

Can anyone explain me why Theano has to go that deep to implement this gradient function? Please correct me if I am wrong: assuming (2,2) max-pooling, I thought all what we need to do is to compute gx from gz (see the grad def below), i.e. getting the gradient of x by upscaling gz to the shape of x and only populates gz elements to those gx elements whose corresponding x elements are maximum in a (2,2) neighborhood.

```
def grad(self, inp, grads):
    x, = inp
    gz, = grads
    if self.mode == 'max':
        maxout = self(x)
        return [MaxPoolGrad(self.ds,
                            ignore_border=self.ignore_border,
                            st=self.st, padding=self.padding)(
                                x, maxout, gz)]
```